# Changing limit values

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm working a problem in which the analysis says,

> $$\lim_{x\to\pi} \frac{x-\pi}{-\sin(x-\pi)}  = \lim_{x\to 0} - \frac x{\sin (x)}$$

It's not clear to me how the limit value can be manipulated like this.  Is there an algebraic way to see this?

Comment: This is just a change of variables: plug in $y = x-\pi$ everywhere on the LHS and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x-\pi = h$ and note that as $x \to \pi$, $h \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi}\frac{x-\pi}{-\sin(x-\pi)}
\end{equation}
 you can replace $x-\pi$ with $y$, so you have:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y}{-\sin(y)}
\end{equation}

It is just a substitution; note that $y\rightarrow 0$ now, because $x\rightarrow \pi$ and $x-\pi=y$.

Comment: Not at all!! ;-)